# How to sort points along a Hilbert curve without using Hilbert indices?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, hilbert-curve

I'm trying to implement the algorithm described in the paper *Fast Hilbert Sort Algorithm Without Using Hilbert Indices* (https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Takeshi_Shinohara/publication/313074453_Fast_Hilbert_Sort_Algorithm_Without_Using_Hilbert_Indices/links/5b8468bd299bf1d5a72b9a0c/Fast-Hilbert-Sort-Algorithm-Without-Using-Hilbert-Indices.pdf?origin=publication_detail), but I can't get the right results.

Below is my python code (For bitset and it's member functions flip and test in C++  , please refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

```
N=9 # 9 points
n=2 # 2 dimension 
m=3 # order of Hilbert curve
b=m-1
def BitTest(x,od,maxlen=3):
    bit=format(x,'b').zfill(maxlen)
    return int(bit[maxlen-1-od])

def BitFlip(b,pos,):
    b ^= 1 << pos
    return b
def partition(A,st,en,od,ax,di):
    i = st
    j = en
    while True:
        while i < j and BitTest(A[i][ax],od)==di:
            i = i + 1
        while i < j and BitTest(A[j][ax],od)!=di:
            j = j - 1
        if i >= j:
            return i
        A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]

def HSort(A,st,en,od,c,e,d,di,cnt):
    if en<=st: 
        return
    p =partition(A,st,en,od,(d+c)%n,BitTest(e,(d+c)%n))
    if c==n-1:
        if b==0:
            return
        d2= (d+n+n-(di if(di==2) else cnt+2))%n
        e=BitFlip(e,d2)
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        HSort(A,st,p-1,b-1,0,e,d2,False,0)
        
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        e=BitFlip(e,d2)
        d2= (d+n+n-(di if(di==cnt+2) else 2))%n
        HSort(A,p+1,en,b-1,0,e,d2,False,0)
    else:
        HSort(A,st,p-1,b,c+1,e,d,False,(di if(di==1) else cnt+1))
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c+1)%n)
        HSort(A,p+1,en,b,c+1,e,d,True,(di if(di==cnt+1) else 1))
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c+1)%n)
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        
array = [[2,2],[2,4],[3,4],[2,5],[3,5],[1,6],[3,6],[5,6],[3,7]]
HSort(array,st=0,en=N-1,od=m-1,c=0,e=0,d=0,di=False,cnt=0)
print(array)
```

Comment: I heavily use a hilbert curve in a project to define the path of visiting each pixel on a given image both when parsing an input image and on flip side with synthesizing an output image after transitioning this input image from freq domain through its time domain representation as audio so am familiar with generating and using the curve ... please explain just what you mean  by `sort`  ... typically the sequence of hilbert curve points is sorted upon synthesis ... would be good if you updated your question with more details and perhaps a hand wrought example of sample input and desired output

Comment: if you have a 2D grid with a given point on this grid which represents a point on the hilbert curve are you asking how to identify an immediate neighbor point without referring to the canonical presorted hilbert curve listing ? ... if this is not a research project having handy this presorted listing will get you the next point ... you may find this repo helpful https://github.com/google/hilbert

Answer (score 2):

That document has a typo, the constant "b" should be replaced with "od".
Here is a working code in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

constexpr std::int32_t m = 3;
constexpr std::int32_t n = 2;

bool test_bit(std::int32_t value, std::int32_t pos)
{
    const auto result = value & (1 << pos);

    return result;
}

void flip_bit(std::int32_t &value, std::int32_t pos)
{
    value ^= 1 << pos;
}

std::int32_t partition(std::vector<std::array<std::int32_t, 2>> &A, std::size_t st, std::size_t en, std::int32_t od, std::int32_t ax, bool di)
{
    std::int32_t i = st - 1;
    std::int32_t j = en + 1;

    while(true)
    {
        do
            i = i + 1;
        while(i < j && test_bit(A[i][ax], od) == di);

        do
            j = j - 1;
        while(i < j && test_bit(A[j][ax], od) != di);

        if(j <= i)
            return i; //partition is complete

        std::swap(A[i], A[j]);
    }
}

void hilbert_sort(std::vector<std::array<std::int32_t, 2>> &A, std::size_t st, std::size_t en, std::int32_t od, std::int32_t c, std::int32_t &e, std::int32_t 
d, bool di, std::int32_t cnt)
{
    std::int32_t p;
    std::int32_t d2;

    if(en <= st)
        return;

    p = partition(A, st, en, od, (d + c) % n, test_bit(e, (d + c) % n));

    if(c == n - 1)
    {
        if(od == 0)
            return;

        d2 = (d + n + n - (di ? 2 : cnt + 2)) % n;

        flip_bit(e, d2);
        flip_bit(e, (d + c) % n);

        hilbert_sort(A, st, p - 1, od - 1, 0, e, d2, false, 0);

        flip_bit(e, (d + c) % n);
        flip_bit(e, d2);

        d2 = (d + n + n - (di ? cnt + 2 : 2)) % n;

        hilbert_sort(A, p, en, od - 1, 0, e, d2, false, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        hilbert_sort(A, st, p - 1, od, c + 1, e, d, false, di ? 1 : cnt + 1); 

        flip_bit(e, (d + c) % n);
        flip_bit(e, (d + c + 1) % n);

        hilbert_sort(A, p, en, od, c + 1, e, d, true, di ? cnt + 1 : 1); 

        flip_bit(e, (d + c + 1) % n);
        flip_bit(e, (d + c) % n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::int32_t, 2>> points = {{2,2},{2,4},{3,4},{2,5},{3,5},{1,6},{3,6},{5,6},{3,7}};

    std::int32_t e = 0;

    hilbert_sort(points, 0, points.size() - 1, m - 1, 0, e, 0, false , 0);

    for(const auto &point : points)
        std::clog << "(" << point[0] << ", " << point[1] << ")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

You also seems to have a typo "p+1" it should be just "p".
Here is a working python code:

```
N=9 # 9 points
n=2 # 2 dimension 
m=3 # order of Hilbert curve
def BitTest(x,od):
    result = x & (1 << od)
    return int(bool(result))

def BitFlip(b,pos):
    b ^= 1 << pos
    return b
def partition(A,st,en,od,ax,di):
    i = st
    j = en
    while True:
        while i < j and BitTest(A[i][ax],od) == di:
            i = i + 1
        while i < j and BitTest(A[j][ax],od) != di:
            j = j - 1
            
        if j <= i:
            return i
        
        A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]

def HSort(A,st,en,od,c,e,d,di,cnt):
    if en<=st: 
        return
    p = partition(A,st,en,od,(d+c)%n,BitTest(e,(d+c)%n))

    if c==n-1:
        if od==0:
            return
        
        d2= (d+n+n-(2 if di else cnt + 2)) % n
        e=BitFlip(e,d2)
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        HSort(A,st,p-1,od-1,0,e,d2,False,0)
        
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        e=BitFlip(e,d2)
        d2= (d+n+n-(cnt + 2 if di else 2))%n
        HSort(A,p,en,od-1,0,e,d2,False,0)
    else:
        HSort(A,st,p-1,od,c+1,e,d,False,(1 if di else cnt+1))
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c+1)%n)
        HSort(A,p,en,od,c+1,e,d,True,(cnt+1 if di else 1))
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c+1)%n)
        e=BitFlip(e,(d+c)%n)
        
array = [[2,2],[2,4],[3,4],[2,5],[3,5],[1,6],[3,6],[5,6],[3,7]]
HSort(array,st=0,en=N-1,od=m-1,c=0,e=0,d=0,di=False,cnt=0)
print(array)
```